# Can you craft a magic item that's both a staff and a magic weapon?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, weapons, crafting

I'm looking a lot into the rules of magic item creation for a Pathfinder campaign. One of my friends playing in the campaign is a big D&D aficionado who remembers some rules about combining several types of magic items into one item, for example a magic weapon that is also a staff.

[The description of typical staves](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/staves) seems quite unambiguous about what a staff is supposed to be, but [the magic items creation rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Creating-Staves) are nebulous about what a staff can be made of exactly.

Is it possible by RAW to craft a magic item combining two types of magic items ?

Comment: [Related.](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/65802/8610)

Comment: I'm a little confused as to the question. Is the question *Can I put the powers of a magic staff into a magic greatsword or a magic ring instead?* or is the question *Can I make a magic staff into a +1 flaming/+1 defending quarterstaff?*

Comment: It goes even further : it's about having absolutely anything become a staff, even a totally random item like a statuette, that could also be a wondrous item at the same time.

Comment: Is it appearance only that matters? That is, is it sufficient to reskin a staff into a figurine or other inoffensive held item?

Comment: It's not only about appearence : for a more practical example, even a weapon could be used as the base for a staff, and also be a magic weapon itself at the same time. This would allow to have a +2 distance musket that also works as a staff that can cast ablative sphere and stone skin.

Comment: @FlashRebel Staves as essentially sticks with spell charges in them. Where do you get the idea that *any* object can be used for the staff base?

Comment: @Mike Q Apparently it was a thing in D&D 3.5, although I could never find any rule that explicitly said that you could do it, the thing is I found no rule that said you couldn't.

Comment: [*The rules don't say I can't* usually isn't the best tack to take.](http://xkcd.com/1552/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rules you quoted answer you, with one exception:

### No, you cannot make just anything a staff.

However, based on certain named Staves and other Wondrous Items, you ***could* make a quarterstaff, cudgel (or other weapon by GM Fiat) 'staff'** that is also an Enhanced Weapon.

From [Creating Magic Items (Staves)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Creating-Staves):

> To create a magic staff, a character needs a supply of materials, **the most obvious being a staff**...

And from [Staves](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/staves)

> Physical Description: A typical staff measures anywhere from 4 feet to 7 feet long and is 2 inches to 3 inches thick, weighing about 5 pounds. Most staves are wood, but an exotic few are bone, metal, or even glass. A staff often has a gem or some device at its tip or is shod in metal at one or both ends. Staves are often decorated with carvings or runes. **A typical staff also functions as a walking stick, quarterstaff, or cudgel.**

Finally, some examples of weapons with Enhancements that are also Staves:

[Staff of Power](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/staves/staff-of-power) "..is also a +2 quarterstaff..."

[Staff of the Hierophant](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/staves/staff-of-the-hierophant) "...is also a +2/+2 quarterstaff..."